# Почему не работает array_push() в классе?

Tags: php

У меня есть класс.
Там есть метод, который добавляет (должен) добавлять новый элемент в конец массива.
Вместо этого происходит ахинея.

Вместо одного элемента в конец массива добавляется 3 элемента, при том добавляется только один первый символ.

Вопрос: что я делаю не так? Как исправить эту проблему?

UPD.
То, что добавляется в конец массива:
[image]

А мне надо чтобы вместо того, что добавилось - добавилась одна запись:
Круглов Илья 20

class.php

```
class Students {
.......
public $arr=array();
public function AddStud($surname, $name, $age) {
        array_push($this->arr, "$surname", "$name", "$age");
    }
}
```

index.php

```
................
<?
include 'class.php';
$s = new Students;
$s->AddStud("Круглов", "Илья", 20);
?>
```

UPD2. Информацию вывожу в таблицу следующим образом:

```
<table>
<? foreach ($s->arr as $f) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><? echo $f["Фамилия"]; ?></td>
      <td><? echo $f["Имя"]; ?></td>
      <td><? echo $f["Возраст"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Второй аргумент в array_push - перечисление значений которые нужно добавить. По этому все 3 и добавляются.

Comment: @kotleni, отредактировал немного вопрос (дополнил картинкой). Вы бы могли подсказать, как сделать так, чтобы получилось то, что мне нужно?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду массив в массиве нужен? ```$arr[] = array("$surname", "$name","$age");```

Comment: ну тогда `array_push($this->arr, [$surname, $name, $age]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша проблема у меня не воспроизводится. Но есть так или иначе куча других проблем.

1. Само добавление `array_push($this->arr, "$surname", "$name", "$age");` некорректно, потому что вы добавляете в нумерованный массив данные. И получается вот что:

   ```
    $s->AddStud("Круглов", "Илья", 20);
    $s->AddStud("Привет", "Андрей", 30);

    Array
    (
        [0] => Круглов
        [1] => Илья
        [2] => 20
        [3] => Привет
        [4] => Андрей
        [5] => 30
    )
   ```

   Как вы понимаете это совсем не корректно.
2. Если даже исправить пуш на этот:

   ```
    array_push($this->arr, [$surname, $name, $age]);
   ```

   То получим что-то уже лучшее:

   ```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Круглов
                [1] => Илья
                [2] => 20
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Привет
                [1] => Андрей
                [2] => 30
            )

    )
   ```
3. Но даже в случае выше, работа у вас просто неверна сразу. Потому что класс в данном случае должен знать только о себе и ни о каких других пользователях. По сути, студент - это отдельная сущность, и он должен знать только о себе: о своей фамилии, о своём имени и своём возрасте. А вы пихаете ему всё сразу.

   Тут надо либо просто отдельно массив с пользователями хранить:

   ```
    <?php


    class Student {

        public $lastname;
        public $name;
        public $age;

        public function __construct($lastname, $name, $age) {
            $this->lastname = $lastname;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age;
        }
    }

    $staticData = [
        ['lastname' => "Круглов", 'name' => "Илья", 'age' => 20],
        ['lastname' => "Привет", 'name' => "Андрей", 'age' => 30],
    ];

    $arrOfStudenrs = [];

    foreach ($staticData as $data) {
        $arrOfStudenrs[] = new Student($data['lastname'], $data['name'], $data['age']);
    }


    print_r($arrOfStudenrs);


    Array
    (
        [0] => Student Object
            (
                [lastname] => Круглов
                [name] => Илья
                [age] => 20
            )

        [1] => Student Object
            (
                [lastname] => Привет
                [name] => Андрей
                [age] => 30
            )

    )
   ```

   Либо делать итерируемую коллекцию со студентами

   ```
    class UserRepository {
        public $studenrts = [];



        public function addStudend(Student $student) {
            array_push($this->studenrts , $student));
        }

        // методы для итерирования и доступа к коллекции
    }
   ```

   И уже работать с этой коллекцией

---

На самом деле на этом проблемы не заканчиваются. Там ещё много нюансов. Но это вам нужно учить ООП.  Долго. :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пытаюсь внедрить тот пуш, который Вы показали, чтобы посмотреть на изменения:  `array_push($this->arr, ["$surname", "$name", "$age"]);`
Видимо мы работаем на разных php, вероятно, у меня более старая версия и возникает такая ошибка: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`

Comment: @dbUser11 внимательнее скобки открывай/закрывай

Comment: @dbUser11 да, я написал для версии >=5.4... Где вы такую древность откопали?)).... Кстати, кавычки там тоже не нужны, поправил.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да так... преподы юзают Денвер, а там старый пхп...
Нагуглил, что нужно использовать вместо `[]`, получилось так: 
`array_push($this->arr, array($surname, $name, $age));`, но все равно не работает

Comment: @dbUser11 да, всё так, вместо `[...]` надо писать `array(...)`. А что значит не работает? Наверное у вас проблемы с выводом информации, а не занесением (или не только с занесением)

Comment: @dbUser11 потому что так-то всё рабочее http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c04fa24739b7beab0d1987612c202429be381429

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в таблицу почему-то не заносится тот студент, которого я добавляю. Его просто нет. Хотя все отработало без синтаксических ошибок. Семантических тоже нет: сначала заношу значение, потом показываю таблицу.

Отредактировал пост, показал вывод массива

Comment: @dbUser11 всё правильно. вы заносите данные под ключами целочисленными, а выводите через ключ->значение из ассоциативного массива. Либо вам надо выводить как `$f[0];`/ `$f[1];`/`$f[2];` Либо заносить в массив так: `array_push($this->arr, array("Фамилия" => $surname, "Имя" => $name, "Возраст" => $age));`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, все стало настолько идеально что даже добавить нечего! Огромное спасибо!)